# python: sort array when sorting other array

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,3,4,2,6])
b = np.array(['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
```

These two array are linked (in the sense that there is a 1-1 correspondence between the elements of the two arrays), so when i sort a by decreasing order I would like to sort b in the same order.

For instance, when I do:

```
a = np.sort(a)[::-1]
```

I get:

```
a = [6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

and I would like to be able to get also:

```
b = ['g', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'c']
```

Comment: The arrays are not linked, apart from logically, by you. Why can you not just sort `b` in the same way?

Comment: How can I sort b in the same way? I mean, the elements in b do not have their own order, they are only linked to those in a

Comment: Sorry - didn't actually look at 'b'! Clearly it can't be sorted. The point remains that they are *not* linked, except by you. I'd have thought the simplest would be to have the elements of `a` and `b` in a single structure (`[(1,'c'), ... ,(6,'g')]`, for example) and sort by the first element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would do smth like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,4,2,6])
b = np.array(['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
idx_order =  np.argsort(a)[::-1]
a = a[idx_order]
b = b[idx_order]
```

output:

```
a = [6 4 3 2 1]
b = ['g' 'e' 'd' 'f' 'c']
```

Comment: I get the following error (regarding the last line): only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: please update the question with your new code, the intermediate variables and the error message

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how or even if you can do this in numpy arrays. However there is a way using standard lists albeit slightly convoluted. Consider this:-

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 2, 6]
b = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
assert len(a) == len(b)
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append((a[i], b[i]))
r = sorted(c)
for i in range(len(r)):
    a[i], b[i] = r[i]
print(a)
print(b)
```

In your problem statement, there is no relationship between the two tables. What happens here is that we make a relationship by grouping relevant data from each table into a temporary list of tuples. In this scenario, sorted() will carry out an ascending sort on the first element of each tuple. We then just rebuild our original arrays